# How to define CSS layering order?

Tags: css, position, fixed

[image: order]

How can I put box1 behind box2?

[image: expected order]

```
<div class="box2">username</div> -> position: fixed; 
<div class="box1">logo</div> -> position:relative;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using z-index property.

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Refer following :

- z-index positioning : [z-index positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
- CSS Positioning : [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.box1{z-index:1}
.box2{z-index:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define "TOP" position

```
.box2 {position: fixed;  top: 0; }
```